# Unknown attribute android:fullBackupContent

Tags: android, backup

I am trying to implement the backup functionality for my app, but I am running into the following problem:

- android studio tells me to set the `android:fullBackupContent` attribute
- when I set this it tells me that the attribute is not recognized

Here is how I have done above in the manifest xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.balla.popoint">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@res/xml/backup_rules.xml"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/PoPointTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

This is how the backup_rules.xml file looks like:

```
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
    <include domain="root" path="./somefilename"/>
</full-backup-content>`
```

The warning that I get is this:

> ```
> Unknown attribute android:fullBackupContent
> Inspection info: This inspection highlights unknown XML attributes in Android resource files and AndroidManifest.xml
> ```

Why is this warning displayed? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did u solve the issue ?

Comment: Kindly provide the answer how did u solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Change  `android:fullBackupContent="@res/xml/backup_rules.xml"` to `android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"` 
Also make sure the syntax of your file agrees with the following:

```
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain=["file" | "database" | "sharedpref" | "external" | "root"]
    path="string"
    requiredFlags=["clientSideEncryption" | "deviceToDeviceTransfer"] />
    <exclude domain=["file" | "database" | "sharedpref" | "external" | "root"]
    path="string" />
</full-backup-content>
```

[source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#XMLSyntax)

Comment: If I change the path of the fullBackupContent attribute as suggested, I get one more warning, which states: Missing <full-backup-content> resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor
```

Delete this line from your manifest file